# How does a chain of some family of sets $\left\{A\right\}$ differ from $\mathscr{P}\left(\left\{A\right\}\right)$? Must $\left\{A\right\}$ be indexed?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On page 123 of Bloch's *Proofs and Fundamentals*, he states the following definition (3.5.4):

> Let $\mathit{A}$ *[I have changed it to $\mathit{A}$ to avoid
>   confusion]* be a non-empty family of sets.
>
> 1. Let $M\in\mathit{A}$. The set $M$ is a maximal element of $\mathit{A}$ if there is no $Q\in\mathit{A}$ such that
>      $M\subsetneqq Q$.
> 2. Let $C\subseteq \mathit{A}$. The family $C$ is a *chain* if $A,B\in C$ implies $A\subseteq B$ or $A\supseteq B$.

Then he says that a chain is "intuitively" a "subset of $\mathit{A}$ for which the elements can be lined up in order of **inclusion**."

What does he mean by "inclusion"? Could someone please provide an example for the sake of my understanding of this idea?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Note that the elements of $A$ are sets, so "inclusion" is the usual inclusion of sets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To minimise confusion, let me indicate sets of sets with calligraphic letters, i.e. let me write $\mathcal{A}$ instead of $A$ and $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ instead of $C$. Since the elements of $\mathcal{A}$ are sets, so are the elements of $\mathcal{C}$ and in 2. $A \subseteq B$ denotes the usual set inclusion for $A,B \in \mathcal{C}$.

Since you ask for an example, suppose $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{P}(\{1,2,3\})$. Then $$\mathcal{C} = \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$$ is a chain but $$\mathcal{D} = \{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}$$ is not.

Comment: I couldn't get "\mathcal{}" to work, MathJax has been all over the place lately, so I simply chose "\mathit{}". For some reason yours comes up, however. Thanks! This makes sense now